# cannot import name 'bayesflow' tensorflow 1.4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

As others have mentioned I need to update dask, I did so,and now conda says that it is correct. Still tensorflow can't find it. WTF

SONY@instance-1:~/anaconda3/pkgs$ conda install dask
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

SONY@instance-1:~/anaconda3/pkgs$ conda update dask
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.4.1'

>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/SONY/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-
from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
ImportError: cannot import name 'bayesflow'
```

Seriously WTF!!
How do I get around this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got rid off it in the most CS way possible.
Uninstalled tensorflow, Anaconda.

Installed Anaconda for python 3.6, Installed tensorflow-gpu with version 1.4.1

And it worked like a charm. tf uses gpu and doesn't complain about bayesflow

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are importing as `tf`--but then you use `tensorflow.whatever` instead of `tf.whatever`.  Secondly, your error has nothing to do with the imports you posted.

Comment: Seriously?
I ran
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data


On my aws instance and it worked. It has python 2.7.12 and 
tf.__version__ is 1.3.0

Comment: On my local system I have conda and python 3,5 with tensorflow 1.4.1, and it does not work.

Comment: When you tell python that you are importing tensorflow as tf, then you have to use tf as the module name--not tensorflow.  You should be getting an error like, `NameError: name 'tensorflow' is not defined`.  How about you just write `import tensorflow` and see what happens?  *On my aws instance and it worked.*-- Then somewhere the statement: `import tensorflow` gets executed.

Comment: That is surely not an issue, Otherwise it would not work with python 2.7.12.
There is something shaky happening with Anaconda and Tensforflow. 
Because import tensorflow as tf and from tensorflow... import ... are surely different statements

Comment: I do not know, but if you use the name tensorflow, then somewhere the line `import tensorflow` got executed, and writing `import tensorflow as tf` is a waste of time if you never use the name tf.